# Copying a file to jenkins workspace location

Tags: jenkins, xcopy

I need to copy one file to the workspace location of jenkins for my pipeline jenkins job. For that I need to use bat command for windows.
What is the bat command to copy the file from one source location to the destination location.
I have used the code like

```
bat '''xcopy /Y /s "<source location>"*.*"<Destination location>"'''
```

The above code was getting the error as file not found but i have provided the right path of the files. Can anyone please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do with the `*.*` but if you just want to copy a file from the source location to the destination, you should use:

```
bat '''xcopy /Y /s "<source location>" "<Destination location>"'''
```

no `*.*`. You will get file not found with `*.*`. If this doesn't fulfill your needs, then elaborate on exactly what you are trying to do here and I should be able to help.

Comment: @M B thanks for the info. I have removed ```*.*``` but i was getting the error as ```Cannot perform a cyclic copy```. Can u please suggest me what would be the another way to get copied a file from one source directory to destination. Please help me out with this.

Comment: Your error is due to a different reason. You are trying to copy  from a folder that contains the target folder. Post an example of what your `source location` and `target location` is. You are probably trying to do something like copy a parent directory into the child directory of the same folder